# opencart error "mod_fcgid: stderr" on extension-modification refresh

Tags: php, opencart, http-status-code-500, opencart-3, opencart-module

im trying to setup a new theme on opencart i copied theme files and when i refresh admin->modification i get `HTTP ERROR 500`

i checked my PHP log and it is showing
`[Fri Jul 24 14:46:24.728945 2020] [fcgid:warn] [pid 25558] [client] mod_fcgid: stderr:   thrown in /home/mysite/public_html/admin/controller/marketplace/modification.php on line 141, referer: https://www.##.com/admin/index.php?route=marketplace/modification&user_token=Lh3NhQNlv4eueMmuI79naXF4TLFe9BWB`

i have tried to increase memory_limit in php.ini but no success

any help would be appreciated

Comment: I now, it's OC3, but maybe. Some themes requires VQMOD. do you have `vqmod` folder in site root?

Comment: i figured out myself, it was the extension phpxml, i installed it sudo apt-get install php7.3-xml and restarted apache sudo service apache2 restart, it worked!